Optimal validation of an object in C++ if it receives raw data
I receive data entered by the user and I need to initialize a class with it that has an abstract parent class. I can do the check before initializing the class, but in this way the class validation logic will be taken out of it, which will lead to code duplication and/or repeated code execution. I can think of many ways to do this, but they all seem suboptimal to me.
Could you help me with this, tell me how to solve such problems? Maybe they can be solved in completely different ways.
Methods that I have considered
Throwing an exception in the constructor:
It seems like the best option BUT since raw data can and will be supplied as input, it turns out that the exception will be used to control the progress of the program, which is not recommended as I understand it.
The test on https://quick-bench.com showed, in my opinion, a very slow exception processing speed, but in practice because I am writing for a microcontroller, then throwing an exception takes 61 ms, which is unacceptable for such a situation, as it seems to me.
Object validity flag:
If the class is used frequently, this will impose additional costs compared to a one-time check.
Forces checking the validity of the object in each method.
And the worst thing is that it imposes restrictions on the return values, for example the use of std::optional, which will require a bunch of checks wherever methods are called.
Creating an object, validating it, deleting it if not valid:
It seems like a good option, but it imposes additional costs on creating the object.
Creation using a static method or the builder/factory pattern:
Let me make a reservation that this means checking the validity before creating the object.
I have settled on this option for now, but checking the validity of a class before creating it in the conditions of an abstract parent class creates a complex organization of code, it seems to me. The main problem is the duplication of code for validating setter data and validating data for the constructor. In order to reduce code repetition, the setter has to call static methods of the created class, which, in turn, call general checks implemented for the setter in the abstract class in order to reduce code repetition, and class-specific checks. And since the setter is a member of an abstract class, in order to call a static method of the created class, it needs to delegate this to a virtual function.
#include <optional>

class FavoriteNum {
protected:
    int favorite;

public:
    virtual int compute() const = 0;

    // Setter
    bool setFavorite(int i) {
        if (v_isFavoriteValidation(i)) {
            favorite = i;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

protected:
    FavoriteNum(int i) :favorite(i) {};

    virtual bool v_isFavoriteValidation(int i) = 0;

    // Сommon for children
    static bool biggerOrEqual(int newFavorite, int favorite) {
        return newFavorite >= favorite;
    }
};

class Favorite2 : public FavoriteNum {
protected:
    Favorite2(int i) :FavoriteNum(i) {};
    static constexpr int default_favorite = 2;

public:
    // Doesn't matter, some logic
    int compute() const override {
        return favorite * 2;
    };

    // Builder, there could be a static function here, it doesn't matter what exactly
    class FavoriteBuilder {
    protected:
        int val;

    public:
        FavoriteBuilder& setVal(int i) {
            val = i;
            return *this;
        };

        std::optional<Favorite2*> build() {
            if (isFavoriteValidation(val, default_favorite)) {
                return new Favorite2(val);
            }
            return std::nullopt;
        };
    };

protected:
    // Virtual func for validation in setter, just delegate work 
    bool v_isFavoriteValidation(int i) override {
        return isFavoriteValidation(i, favorite);
    }

    // Static func for validation in builder and aggregation of validation functions
    static bool isFavoriteValidation(int i, int curFavorite) {
        return biggerOrEqual(i, curFavorite) && isFavoriteNumber(i);
    }

    // Specific for class validation logic
    static bool isFavoriteNumber(int i) {
        return i % 6 == 0;
    }
};


there is no way that is optimal / the best in every situation. The alternatives you mention can be made to work properly. You can choose one of them.

Seriously, you are constructing an object from user data... and then you're concerned about a few ms exception handling? Usually, I use one of these two: throw an error from the constructor, or make an bool init() function that can return a false. Although there might be a throw/catch internally as well -- in both cases. since I generally like to throw something like InvalidData, so other errors bypass that catch. I don't do "invalid state" from constructors, and I don't think I've ever used factory calls for error checking purposes.
